Error in <TTree::SetBranchAddress>: unknown branch
I want to print out the coordinates x, y, z, plane, bar, signalPosition, signalTime, and data from the output tree. However, when I print them, the results are incorrect and appear as shown in the image.
Program Output
Stack trace
My code:
#include <TFile.h>
#include <TTree.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

void readOutputTree() {
    TFile* file = TFile::Open("/home/lecamvi/Documents/TOF_thesis/output/run16480_outputTree.root", "READ");
    if (!file || file->IsZombie()) {
        std::cerr << "Error opening file" << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    TTree* tree = (TTree*)file->Get("TofHitsTree");
    if (!tree) {
        std::cerr << "Error getting tree" << std::endl;
        file->Close();
        return;
    }

    int plane, bar;
    double x, y, z, signalTime, signalPosition;

    tree->SetBranchAddress("plane", &plane);
    tree->SetBranchAddress("bar", &bar);
    tree->SetBranchAddress("x", &x);
    tree->SetBranchAddress("y", &y);
    tree->SetBranchAddress("z", &z);
    tree->SetBranchAddress("signalTime", &signalTime);
    tree->SetBranchAddress("signalPosition", &signalPosition);

    std::ofstream outFile("output.txt");
    if (!outFile) {
        std::cerr << "Error creating output file" << std::endl;
        file->Close();
        return;
    }

    Long64_t entries = tree->GetEntries();
    for (Long64_t i = 0; i < entries; i++) {
        tree->GetEntry(i);
        outFile << "Entry " << i << ": "
                << "plane = " << plane << ", "
                << "bar = " << bar << ", "
                << "x = " << x << ", "
                << "y = " << y << ", "
                << "z = " << z << ", "
                << "signalTime = " << signalTime << ", "
                << "signalPosition = " << signalPosition << std::endl;
    }

    outFile.close();
    file->Close();
}


Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

Also, please [edit] and share a [mre]. We don't know the contents of the header files you #include, we don't know what's in the file you open. Like this, nobody will be able to reproduce your issue.

Could you share your run16480_outputTree.root for us to inspect?

From the stack trace it looks like your branch names are not correct. If it's a file you didn't generate, the branch names can be printed for verification by something that looks like this:
TObjArray* branches = tree->GetListOfBranches();                               
for(int i = 0; i < branches->GetEntries(); i++){
  std::cout<<"\""<<branches->At(i)->GetName()<<"\""<<endl;
}

This should print out all the branch names and that would make it clear if you've missed any whitespace, etc. in the branch names you use. Alternatively, you can also do,
tree->Print();

It's also good practice to initialize the variables whose ownership is taken by the branches. For example, instead of
int plane, bar;
double x, y, z, signalTime, signalPosition;

do this
int plane = 0, bar = 0;
double x = 0, y = 0, z = 0, signalTime = 0, signalPosition = 0;

You can obviously replace the zeros with initial values that make more sense for your use case.
